# Numeric Data in MySQL displays as Boolean TRUE/FALSE in textboxes on VB 2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a field in my mySQL database which has a dataype of smallint(2). I connected my database to VB 2010 and I can't get the number to display in the textbox. Other numeric values display correctly aside from this one. This particular data only displays TRUE although it is not of the Boolean data type. I checked my BindingSource and indeed VB 2010 recognizes it as boolean when it shouldn't.

Comment: The `(2)` is just a hint to mysql on how many digits to display. Internally there's only ever `smallint`, even if you're saving more than 2 digits into it - it's still a 2byte field.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, I saw what's wrong. On VB 2010 I went to the dataset deisgner and found out that the particular field's datatype is system.boolean, I just changed it to system.int16 and everything's working no